Hansen solubility parameters and HMPC
Finding solvents for HMPC
I am trying to gather information about hydroxypropyl methylcellulose (HPMC) — a.k.a. hypromellose or under the trade name Methocel — solubility in a variety of solvents. HPMC is known to be extensively soluble in water — above 60m% for instance[1] — however, I had difficulties finding solubility values for HPMC in other (organic) solvents. Archer et al. reported solubility in DMSO, benzyl alcohol, or formamide[2], but solubility in other solvents remains largely unknown to the best of my knowledge.
Hansen solubility parameters
Thus, my idea was to use Hansen solubility parameters. From what I understood, each solvent and polymer may be described by three solubility parameters, $\delta_d$, $\delta_p$ and $\delta_h$, which allow to compute the interaction radius $R_a$ for a solvent / polymer pair as
$R_a^2 = 4\cdot (\delta_{d,solv} - \delta_{d,poly})^2 + (\delta_{p,solv} - \delta_{p,poly})^2 + (\delta_{h,solv} - \delta_{h,poly})^2$
This $R_a$ can then be compared to the radius of interaction of the polymer itself, $R_0$. If $R_0 > R_a$ (i.e. if $R_a / R_0 < 1$), the polymer will dissolve into the solvent.
Parameters database
I found Zeng et al. database of Hansen solubility parameters[3], available here as CSV. And used the Hansen solubility parameters available in Archer's publication for HPMC, e.g. $\delta_d = 17.4$, $\delta_p = 14.6$, $\delta_h = 15.5$ (MPa$^{1/2}$, see Table V) to compute the RED = $R_a / R_0$ ratio for all solvents. RED values below 1 should mean good solubility, while values above 1 should mean poor solubility / insolubility.
Results
Sorted alphabetically:                                 Sorted by ascending RED:
1,1,1Trichloroethane, RED = 1.65                       Diethylenetriamine, RED = 0.21
1,1,2,2Tetrachloroethane, RED = 1.13                   N,NDimethylformamide, RED = 0.42
1,1Dichloroethane, RED = 1.60                          N,NDimethylformamide, RED = 0.42
1,1Dichloroethylene, RED = 1.31                        AllylAlcohol, RED = 0.45
1,2,3,4Tetrahydronaphthalene, RED = 1.78               3Hydroxypropionitrile, RED = 0.46
1,2Dibromoethane, RED = 0.93                           DipropyleneGlycol, RED = 0.48
1,2Dichlorobenzene, RED = 1.47                         SuccinicAnhydride, RED = 0.51
1,2Dichloroethane, RED = 1.35                          TrimethylPhosphate, RED = 0.54
1,3Dimethylcyclohexane, RED = 2.01                     DimethylSulfoxide, RED = 0.58
1,3Dioxolane, RED = 0.99                               2Methoxyethanol, RED = 0.58
1,4Diethylbenzene, RED = 2.03                          2Ethoxyethanol, RED = 0.59
1,4Dioxane, RED = 1.50                                 Ethylenediamine, RED = 0.60
1Butanol, RED = 0.91                                   N,NDimethylacetamide, RED = 0.61
1Chlorobutane, RED = 1.59                              2Pyrrolidinone, RED = 0.63
1Chloropropane, RED = 1.49                             DimethylSulfone, RED = 0.64
1Decanol, RED = 1.27                                   AceticAnhydride, RED = 0.65
1Methoxy2Propanol, RED = 0.96                          Sulfolane, RED = 0.65
1Methyl2Pyrrolidinone, RED = 0.84                      DiethyleneGlycolMonoethylEther, RED = 0.65
1Methylnaphthalene, RED = 1.81                         FormicAcid, RED = 0.67
1Octanol, RED = 1.15                                   TetrahydrofurfurylAlcohol, RED = 0.68
1Phenoxy2Propanol, RED = 0.98                          FurfurylAlcohol, RED = 0.68
1Propanol, RED = 0.83                                  TriethylPhosphate, RED = 0.69
1Tridecanol, RED = 1.42                                Hexamethylphosphoramide, RED = 0.74
2,2ButoxyethoxyEthylAcetate, RED = 1.27                Ethanol, RED = 0.75
2,6Dimethyl4Heptanone, RED = 1.56                      Ethanolamine, RED = 0.75
2Butanol, RED = 0.92                                   Ethanolamine, RED = 0.75
2Butanol, RED = 0.92                                   DiethyleneGlycolMethylEther, RED = 0.75
2Butanone, RED = 1.18                                  Tetramethylurea, RED = 0.77
2ButoxyethylAcetate, RED = 1.16                        EthylLactate, RED = 0.79
2ChloroethylEther, RED = 1.13                          GammaButyrolactone, RED = 0.82
2Ethoxyethanol, RED = 0.59                             Resorcinol, RED = 0.82
2EthoxyethylAcetate, RED = 1.11                        1Propanol, RED = 0.83
2Furaldehyde, RED = 1.04                               Methanol, RED = 0.83
2Methoxyethanol, RED = 0.58                            4Hydroxy4Methyl2Pentanone, RED = 0.83
2Methyl1Propanol, RED = 0.97                           MCresol, RED = 0.83
2Nitropropane, RED = 1.16                              1Methyl2Pyrrolidinone, RED = 0.84
2Octanol, RED = 1.06                                   NMethylpyrrolidine, RED = 0.84
2Pentanone, RED = 1.28                                 BenzylAlcohol, RED = 0.85
2Propanol, RED = 0.89                                  Phenol, RED = 0.85
2Pyrrolidinone, RED = 0.63                             DiethylSulfate, RED = 0.86
3Chloro1Propanol, RED = 0.87                           3Chloro1Propanol, RED = 0.87
3Hexanol, RED = 1.07                                   AceticAcid, RED = 0.87
3Hydroxypropionitrile, RED = 0.46                      EthyleneGlycolMonophenylEther, RED = 0.88
3Methyl1Butanol, RED = 0.99                            2Propanol, RED = 0.89
3Pentanone, RED = 1.29                                 Caprolactone, RED = 0.91
4Hydroxy4Methyl2Pentanone, RED = 0.83                  1Butanol, RED = 0.91
4Hydroxymethyl1,3Dioxolan2One, RED = 1.08              Acrylonitrile, RED = 0.91
4Methyl2Pentanol, RED = 1.21                           DiethyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 0.92
4Methyl2Pentanone, RED = 1.44                          Acetaldehyde, RED = 0.92
4Octanol, RED = 1.18                                   2Butanol, RED = 0.92
5Methyl2Hexanone, RED = 1.43                           2Butanol, RED = 0.92
Acetaldehyde, RED = 0.92                               1,2Dibromoethane, RED = 0.93
AceticAcid, RED = 0.87                                 BenzoicAcid, RED = 0.94
AceticAnhydride, RED = 0.65                            1Methoxy2Propanol, RED = 0.96
Acetone, RED = 0.99                                    2Methyl1Propanol, RED = 0.97
Acetonitrile, RED = 1.05                               1Phenoxy2Propanol, RED = 0.98
Acetophenone, RED = 1.35                               EthylFormate, RED = 0.99
AcetylChloride, RED = 1.23                             3Methyl1Butanol, RED = 0.99
Acrylonitrile, RED = 0.91                              ButylLactate, RED = 0.99
AllylAlcohol, RED = 0.45                               Acetone, RED = 0.99
AmylAlcohol, RED = 1.03                                1,3Dioxolane, RED = 0.99
Anisole, RED = 1.33                                    DiPropyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 1.01
Benzaldehyde, RED = 1.27                               Nitropropane, RED = 1.01
Benzene, RED = 1.94                                    EthyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 1.01
BenzoicAcid, RED = 0.94                                Isophorone, RED = 1.01
Benzonitrile, RED = 1.30                               TertButanol, RED = 1.02
BenzylAlcohol, RED = 0.85                              EthylChloroformate, RED = 1.02
BenzylBenzoate, RED = 1.45                             DowanolDpm, RED = 1.03
BenzylButylPhthalate, RED = 1.28                       AmylAlcohol, RED = 1.03
BenzylEther, RED = 1.32                                N,NDimethylhydrazine, RED = 1.03
Biphenyl, RED = 2.02                                   2Furaldehyde, RED = 1.04
Bis2ChloroisopropylEther, RED = 1.23                   Cyclohexanol, RED = 1.04
Bromobenzene, RED = 1.54                               Acetonitrile, RED = 1.05
Bromochloromethane, RED = 1.45                         Propionitrile, RED = 1.05
Bromoethane, RED = 1.21                                2Octanol, RED = 1.06
Bromoform, RED = 1.58                                  3Hexanol, RED = 1.07
Bromotrifluoromethane, RED = 2.44                      DiethyleneGlycolDimethylEther, RED = 1.07
Butoxypropanol, RED = 1.23                             4Hydroxymethyl1,3Dioxolan2One, RED = 1.08
ButylAcetate, RED = 1.42                               EthyleneGlycol, RED = 1.08
Butylamine, RED = 1.24                                 PropyleneGlycolMonomethylEtherAcetate, RED = 1.09
ButylBenzoate, RED = 1.32                              Nitroethane, RED = 1.11
ButylLactate, RED = 0.99                               2EthoxyethylAcetate, RED = 1.11
ButylPropionate, RED = 1.33                            Butyronitrile, RED = 1.11
ButylStearate, RED = 1.67                              MethylAcetate, RED = 1.11
Butyraldehyde, RED = 1.33                              DimethylPhthalate, RED = 1.12
ButyricAcid, RED = 1.23                                Cyanol, RED = 1.13
Butyronitrile, RED = 1.11                              2ChloroethylEther, RED = 1.13
Caprolactone, RED = 0.91                               1,1,2,2Tetrachloroethane, RED = 1.13
CarbonDisulfide, RED = 2.11                            Nitromethane, RED = 1.13
CarbonTetrachloride, RED = 2.03                        Pyridine, RED = 1.13
Chlorobenzene, RED = 1.68                              Quinoline, RED = 1.13
Chlorodifluoromethane, RED = 1.59                      TricresylPhosphate, RED = 1.13
Chloroform, RED = 1.47                                 Tetrahydrofuran, RED = 1.14
Chloromethane, RED = 1.45                              1Octanol, RED = 1.15
Cyanol, RED = 1.13                                     Morpholine, RED = 1.16
Cyclohexane, RED = 2.06                                2Nitropropane, RED = 1.16
Cyclohexanol, RED = 1.04                               Propylamine, RED = 1.16
Cyclohexanone, RED = 1.29                              2ButoxyethylAcetate, RED = 1.16
Cyclohexylamine, RED = 1.42                            Ethanethiol, RED = 1.17
DibutylPhthalate, RED = 1.25                           DiethylPhthalate, RED = 1.17
DibutylSebacate, RED = 1.63                            Formamide, RED = 1.18
Dichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.50                      MesitylOxide, RED = 1.18
Dichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.50                      2Butanone, RED = 1.18
Dichloromethane, RED = 1.23                            4Octanol, RED = 1.18
Diethylamine, RED = 1.58                               Bromoethane, RED = 1.21
DiethylCarbonate, RED = 1.45                           4Methyl2Pentanol, RED = 1.21
DiethyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 0.92                 ButyricAcid, RED = 1.23
DiethyleneGlycolDimethylEther, RED = 1.07              Butoxypropanol, RED = 1.23
DiethyleneGlycolMethylEther, RED = 0.75                Bis2ChloroisopropylEther, RED = 1.23
DiethyleneGlycolMonoethylEther, RED = 0.65             Dichloromethane, RED = 1.23
Diethylenetriamine, RED = 0.21                         AcetylChloride, RED = 1.23
DiethylEther, RED = 1.62                               Butylamine, RED = 1.24
DiethylPhthalate, RED = 1.17                           EthylAcetate, RED = 1.25
DiethylSulfate, RED = 0.86                             DibutylPhthalate, RED = 1.25
DiethylSulfide, RED = 1.72                             Epichlorohydrin, RED = 1.26
DiisopropylEther, RED = 1.69                           PropyleneCarbonate, RED = 1.27
DimethylPhthalate, RED = 1.12                          2,2ButoxyethoxyEthylAcetate, RED = 1.27
DimethylSulfone, RED = 0.64                            Benzaldehyde, RED = 1.27
DimethylSulfoxide, RED = 0.58                          1Decanol, RED = 1.27
DiNOctylPhthalate, RED = 1.42                          2Pentanone, RED = 1.28
Dipropylamine, RED = 1.74                              EthyleneCarbonate, RED = 1.28
DipropyleneGlycol, RED = 0.48                          BenzylButylPhthalate, RED = 1.28
DiPropyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 1.01                EthylCinnamate, RED = 1.28
DLLimonene, RED = 1.65                                 3Pentanone, RED = 1.29
DowanolDpm, RED = 1.03                                 Cyclohexanone, RED = 1.29
Epichlorohydrin, RED = 1.26                            Benzonitrile, RED = 1.30
Ethanethiol, RED = 1.17                                IsopropylAcetate, RED = 1.30
Ethanol, RED = 0.75                                    1,1Dichloroethylene, RED = 1.31
Ethanolamine, RED = 0.75                               ButylBenzoate, RED = 1.32
Ethanolamine, RED = 0.75                               BenzylEther, RED = 1.32
EthylAcetate, RED = 1.25                               PropylAcetate, RED = 1.32
Ethylbenzene, RED = 1.93                               ButylPropionate, RED = 1.33
EthylChloroformate, RED = 1.02                         Anisole, RED = 1.33
EthylCinnamate, RED = 1.28                             Butyraldehyde, RED = 1.33
EthyleneCarbonate, RED = 1.28                          PropylPropionate, RED = 1.34
Ethylenediamine, RED = 0.60                            1,2Dichloroethane, RED = 1.35
EthyleneGlycol, RED = 1.08                             Acetophenone, RED = 1.35
EthyleneGlycolButylEther, RED = 1.01                   Nitrobenzene, RED = 1.36
EthyleneGlycolMonophenylEther, RED = 0.88              TributylPhosphate, RED = 1.37
EthylFormate, RED = 0.99                               OctanoicAcid, RED = 1.38
EthylLactate, RED = 0.79                               SecButylAcetate, RED = 1.39
Formamide, RED = 1.18                                  1Tridecanol, RED = 1.42
FormicAcid, RED = 0.67                                 Cyclohexylamine, RED = 1.42
Furan, RED = 1.59                                      ButylAcetate, RED = 1.42
FurfurylAlcohol, RED = 0.68                            DiNOctylPhthalate, RED = 1.42
GammaButyrolactone, RED = 0.82                         MethyleneIodide, RED = 1.42
Heptane, RED = 2.11                                    5Methyl2Hexanone, RED = 1.43
Hexadecafluoroheptane, RED = 2.31                      4Methyl2Pentanone, RED = 1.44
Hexamethylphosphoramide, RED = 0.74                    IsopentylAcetate, RED = 1.45
Hexane, RED = 2.12                                     DiethylCarbonate, RED = 1.45
IsobutylAcetate, RED = 1.46                            Bromochloromethane, RED = 1.45
IsobutylIsobutyrate, RED = 1.55                        BenzylBenzoate, RED = 1.45
IsopentylAcetate, RED = 1.45                           Chloromethane, RED = 1.45
Isophorone, RED = 1.01                                 IsobutylAcetate, RED = 1.46
IsopropylAcetate, RED = 1.30                           PentylAcetate, RED = 1.46
IsopropylPalmitate, RED = 1.66                         Chloroform, RED = 1.47
MCresol, RED = 0.83                                    1,2Dichlorobenzene, RED = 1.47
Mesitylene, RED = 2.03                                 StearicAcid, RED = 1.48
MesitylOxide, RED = 1.18                               TertButylAcetate, RED = 1.48
Methanol, RED = 0.83                                   Tetrachloroethylene, RED = 1.49
MethylAcetate, RED = 1.11                              OleylAlcohol, RED = 1.49
Methylcyclohexane, RED = 2.02                          1Chloropropane, RED = 1.49
MethyleneIodide, RED = 1.42                            Trichloroethylene, RED = 1.50
MethylOleate, RED = 1.65                               Dichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.50
Morpholine, RED = 1.16                                 Dichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.50
Naphthalene, RED = 1.58                                1,4Dioxane, RED = 1.50
Nitrobenzene, RED = 1.36                               Bromobenzene, RED = 1.54
Nitroethane, RED = 1.11                                IsobutylIsobutyrate, RED = 1.55
Nitromethane, RED = 1.13                               2,6Dimethyl4Heptanone, RED = 1.56
Nitropropane, RED = 1.01                               Naphthalene, RED = 1.58
NMethylpyrrolidine, RED = 0.84                         Diethylamine, RED = 1.58
N,NDimethylacetamide, RED = 0.61                       Bromoform, RED = 1.58
N,NDimethylformamide, RED = 0.42                       Furan, RED = 1.59
N,NDimethylformamide, RED = 0.42                       Chlorodifluoromethane, RED = 1.59
N,NDimethylhydrazine, RED = 1.03                       1Chlorobutane, RED = 1.59
OctanoicAcid, RED = 1.38                               OleicAcid, RED = 1.60
OleicAcid, RED = 1.60                                  1,1Dichloroethane, RED = 1.60
OleylAlcohol, RED = 1.49                               DiethylEther, RED = 1.62
OXylene, RED = 1.79                                    DibutylSebacate, RED = 1.63
PentylAcetate, RED = 1.46                              MethylOleate, RED = 1.65
Phenol, RED = 0.85                                     1,1,1Trichloroethane, RED = 1.65
Propionitrile, RED = 1.05                              DLLimonene, RED = 1.65
PropylAcetate, RED = 1.32                              IsopropylPalmitate, RED = 1.66
Propylamine, RED = 1.16                                ButylStearate, RED = 1.67
PropyleneCarbonate, RED = 1.27                         Chlorobenzene, RED = 1.68
PropyleneGlycolMonomethylEtherAcetate, RED = 1.09      DiisopropylEther, RED = 1.69
PropylPropionate, RED = 1.34                           DiethylSulfide, RED = 1.72
Pyridine, RED = 1.13                                   Styrene, RED = 1.74
Quinoline, RED = 1.13                                  Dipropylamine, RED = 1.74
Resorcinol, RED = 0.82                                 1,2,3,4Tetrahydronaphthalene, RED = 1.78
SecButylAcetate, RED = 1.39                            OXylene, RED = 1.79
StearicAcid, RED = 1.48                                1Methylnaphthalene, RED = 1.81
Styrene, RED = 1.74                                    Toluene, RED = 1.84
SuccinicAnhydride, RED = 0.51                          Ethylbenzene, RED = 1.93
Sulfolane, RED = 0.65                                  Benzene, RED = 1.94
TertButanol, RED = 1.02                                Trichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.98
TertButylAcetate, RED = 1.48                           1,3Dimethylcyclohexane, RED = 2.01
Tetrachloroethylene, RED = 1.49                        Methylcyclohexane, RED = 2.02
Tetrahydrofuran, RED = 1.14                            Biphenyl, RED = 2.02
TetrahydrofurfurylAlcohol, RED = 0.68                  CarbonTetrachloride, RED = 2.03
Tetramethylurea, RED = 0.77                            1,4Diethylbenzene, RED = 2.03
Toluene, RED = 1.84                                    Mesitylene, RED = 2.03
TributylPhosphate, RED = 1.37                          Cyclohexane, RED = 2.06
Trichloroethylene, RED = 1.50                          Heptane, RED = 2.11
Trichlorofluoromethane, RED = 1.98                     CarbonDisulfide, RED = 2.11
TricresylPhosphate, RED = 1.13                         Hexane, RED = 2.12
TriethylPhosphate, RED = 0.69                          TrifluoromethylUndecafluorocyclohexane, RED = 2.28
TrifluoromethylUndecafluorocyclohexane, RED = 2.28     TrifluoromethylUndecafluorocyclohexane, RED = 2.28
TrifluoromethylUndecafluorocyclohexane, RED = 2.28     Hexadecafluoroheptane, RED = 2.31
TrimethylPhosphate, RED = 0.54                         Bromotrifluoromethane, RED = 2.44
Water, RED = 2.64                                      Water, RED = 2.64

In particular, the RED values for DMSO, formamide, and water are
DimethylSulfoxide, RED = 0.58
Formamide, RED = 1.18
Water, RED = 2.64

Problem
The issue is that according to the above-presented RED values, HPMC should not be soluble in formamide nor in water(!). How comes?
Note: any help on this topic would be welcome, I am no polymer chemistry expert and I might have grossly overlooked something here.

References
[1] Radiation crosslinking of biodegradable hydroxypropylmethylcellulose, Pekel et al. (2003), DOI: 10.1016/j.carbpol.2003.08.015
[2] Determination of Hansen Solubility Parameters for Selected Cellulose
Ether Derivatives, Archer et al. (1991), DOI: 10.1021/ie00058a008
[3] Solubility Parameters, Zeng et al. (2007), DOI: 10.1007/978-0-387-69002-5_16

HSPs tend to underestimate hydrogen bonding effects, since the solubility distance weighs dispersion forces 4x higher. In addition, HSPs don't make any distinction between hydrogen-donor and hydrogen-acceptor characteristics, so they sometimes don't have enough discriminant power to get behavior right. If you're looking for an alternative, descriptor-based approach, check out the recent work by Panayiotou. He and coworkers have developed "Partial solvation parameters", which essentially break the hydrogen bonding term into hydrogen-donor and hydrogen-acceptor terms.

Thanks, sorry about the late answer. Indeed, for instance in dx.doi.org/10.1039/C2CP23966C the authors show (Table 4) the relatively poor performance of Hansen's solubility parameters compared to theirs.
